# my report run but does not display anything in oracle

Tags: forms, oracle10g, report

I have designed report in 10g. When I call report through forms 10g than report executed but do not display anything. Kindly help me what I have to do to resolve this issue. I use .rep report and desformat is PDF. One thing more when in this desformat my report started downloading instead of giving a preview in internet explorer and downloaded pdf is empty (contain nothing).

Answer (score 0):

Report displays the result of a query. So the most obvious question is: does the query, when you run it outside of the Forms/Reports application, work correctly and returns the result?

If it accepts certain parameters, verify that they are correctly passed. Mind the datatype, especially if DATE is involved as people usually have problems with different format masks, NLS settings and stuff.

Also, check whether those parameters are obligatory or not. If not, report's query should contain something like

```
where (some_value = :parameter_value or :parameter_value is null)
```

Furthermore, make sure that all those parameters are passed to the report. You can display their values in the report, just to see what's going on. Open Reports Paper Layout Editor, go to the margin and - using the *ampersand notation* - display those values, such as

```
Parameter one = &parameter_one
Parameter two = &parameter_two
```